# My simple character counter will not work (problems with getchar())

Tags: c, file-io, counting, getchar

I am writing a program in ANSI C that reads in input.txt through file input redirection, counts how many times each of the letters occurs in said .txt file, and then outputs the result to output.txt.
The code that I have now is this:

```
//
//  Project 2 p2.c
//  
//
//  Created by Richard Angal on 2/4/17.
//
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


    int alphabet[26] = {0};
    int c, i;

    while (EOF != (c = getchar())) {

        printf ("%d", c);
        alphabet[(tolower(c) - 'a')]++;

    }

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        printf("'%c' has %d occurrences.\n", i + 'a', alphabet[i]);
    }
}
```

My input.txt file contains "hello world" but without the quotes.

The problem I am running into is that when i check output.txt, it tells me that for every letter, there are 0 occurrences.

The problem is, I have done multiple print statements to check for errors, including putting a count in the while statement body, and it only increments once.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: works here. You may want to filter out non-letter strings or you'll write outside your array...

Comment: `if(isalpha(c))alphabet[(tolower(c) - 'a')]++;` ... `if(alphabet[i] != 0)printf("'%c' has %d occurrences.\n", i + 'a', alphabet[i]);`

Comment: Do you mean that it accurately prints out how many of each characters are in the file? I wonder what is wrong on my end then...

Comment: yep, works fine here: http://ideone.com/R2ItqL

Comment: what may be happening is that you are ***not*** redirecting the output of your program to `output.txt`, and `output.txt` just happens to contain the results of some previous run of your program when it was not working yet.

Comment: Thanks! I have no idea why it wasn't working on my end. Is there a way for me to set this as resolved?

Comment: That's not what commonly is called ANSI-C (aka C89/90). It did not allow C++-style line comments. And you should get used to modern C, C90 is outdated sinc 17 years.